# Compare today's and yesterday's data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have the following table:

| location | eventdate | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| loc1 | 2021-11-28 | 1 |
| loc2 | 2021-11-28 | 2 |
| loc1 | 2021-11-29 | 1 |
| loc2 | 2021-11-29 | 3 |
| loc1 | 2021-11-30 | 2 |
| loc2 | 2021-11-30 | 5 |

And I'd like to compare the values from the oldest availavle day and the day before that to get this result:

| location | diff |
| --- | --- |
| loc1 | 1 |
| loc2 | 2 |

What's the SQL statement to get this?

Comment: What is your MySQL version? Please tag your question accordingly. You may also want to consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Please go to dbfiddle.uk and create your table(s) and input your data. This reduces duplication of effort, provides a single source of truth and saves on duplication of effort for those who might wish to answer. Help us to help you!

Comment: Is this only today and yesterday? Or any day and its previous day? What have you tried. Hint, use a self-join, join the table to itself with the second table aliased, and make the join criteria suit your question.

Comment: Use 2 copies of your table.

Comment: Here is a fiddle with a socultion joining the table to itself:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6fffc61bd7dc6b672788ac129e27c351
But I have to extend this because I don't know if there is data available for today when I run the select. So I have to compare the max. available the to the day before. Any hint for that?

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out in the comments, you can `JOIN` your table to itself, also known as a [self join](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-self-join/). You can achieve this like so:

```
SELECT 
    CurrentDay.location, 
    CurrentDay.value - PreviousDay.value AS diff
FROM YourTable CurrentDay
INNER JOIN YourTable PreviousDay
    ON CurrentDay.location = PreviousDay.location
    AND CurrentDay.eventdate = DATE_SUB(PreviousDay.eventdate, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

This self join takes your table and joins it to itself on the same `location` but where the `eventdate` differs by 1 day.